# Using a file converted by QtCreator in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qwidget

I've got a file converted by the command: `pyside-uic -o ui_name.py name.ui` and I try to use it in my project.
First file:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui_window = ui_window.Ui_MainWindow()

        self.btn5 = QPushButton(QIcon(),"Open", self)
        self.btn5.move(0, 20)
        self.btn5.resize(70, 20)
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(self.doAction5)

    def doAction5(self):
        self.ui_window.Show()
```

Second (ui_window.py):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
.......
    def Show(self):
    self.show()
```

When I execute the project and press the Button, there is an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'show'
```

I have no idea what to replace it with.

EDIT:
First file code edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've run `pyside-uic -o ui_name.py name.ui`, you'll end up with a python file for the interface, ui_name.py. **Don't change anything in this file.** This file is meant to be imported in your main code, like this:

```
from ui_name import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn5 = QPushButton(QIcon(),"Open", self)
        self.btn5.move(0, 20)
        self.btn5.resize(70, 20)
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(self.doAction5)

        self.show()
```

Comment: My code doesn't have MainWindow class. I edited the question and there's how it looks like. If you could tell where put this code to.

Comment: You have some more problems there. Your class Example inherits from QWidget, but your Ui file is for a QMainWindow. Just use my code instead of your `Example` class and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `window.py` file:

```
from Ui_MyWindow import Ui_myWindow

class myWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_myWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

The name of your **Ui** file  should be something like `Ui_MyWindow.py`, and the class you are importing from there should be something like `Ui_myWindow`

To display your window add this code at the end of your `window.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```